# Magento collection order by name - string value

Tags: magento

I have a grid in front end. and i need to put sort function for that grid column. I need to sort by billing name. I add bellow code into my collection;

```
if(!empty($data['sort_billto'])){
            $collection->addAttributeToSort('billing_name', $data['sort_billto']);
        }
```

From $data['sort_billto'] i am getting asc oe desc. That's fine, because this way works for int values. But not working for string, billing name.

Can anyone please help me.

Thank You

Comment: can you show the code of all the function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually your code should work, the problem may seem elsewhere. Give this a try

```
$collection->setOrder('billing_name', $data['sort_billto'])
```

If this doesnt work, debug your complete code.

HTH

Comment: yes my code is correct. The issue was my form data are storing in the session and then this condition wont check. Thank you for helping everyone.